# Proving Schwarz's theorem for reversal of order of derivative

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

> Show that the function $f(x,y)=xy(x^2-y^2)/(x^2+y^2)$ at $(x,y) \neq (0,0)$ and equal to $0$ when $(x,y)= (0,0)$ does not satisfy conditions of Schwarz's theorem.

Here I am able to find out $f_x(x,y)$ but how to find $f_{yx}(x,y)$

Comment: You only need to concentrate on $(x, y) = (0, 0)$, as the function is too nice at every other point.

Comment: @TheoBendit do you mean $f_{yx}(0,0)$?

Comment: Yep. To calculate it, you'll need to take into account the other points, of course, but at every other point, the function will be analytic.

Comment: @TheoBendit how to calculate other points?

Answer (score 0):

Let's take the partial derivative with respect to $x$ at $(x, y) = (0, 0)$ first. We calculate:
\begin{align*}
f_x(0, 0) &= \lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(0 + h, 0) - f(0, 0)}{h} \\
&= \lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(h, 0)}{h} \\
&= \lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{(h)(0)(h^2 - 0^2)}{h} = 0.
\end{align*}
Similarly for $f_y(0, 0) = 0$. At other points, we have,
\begin{align*}f_x(x,y) &= \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \frac{xy(x^2 - y^2)}{x^2 + y^2} \\
&= \frac{(x^2 + y^2)\frac{\partial}{\partial x}[xy(x^2 - y^2)] - xy(x^2 - y^2)\frac{\partial}{\partial x}[x^2 + y^2]}{(x^2 + y^2)^2} \\
&= \frac{(3yx^2 - y^3)(x^2 + y^2) - xy(x^2 - y^2)(2x)}{(x^2 + y^2)^2} \\
&= y\frac{(3x^2 - y^2)(x^2 + y^2) - 2x^2(x^2 - y^2)}{(x^2 + y^2)^2} \\
&= y\frac{x^4 + 4x^2 y^2 - y^4}{(x^2 + y^2)^2}.
\end{align*}
Therefore,
\begin{align*}
f_{xy}(0, 0) &= \lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{f_x(0, 0 + h) - f_x(0, 0)}{h} \\
&= \lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{f_x(0, h)}{h} \\
&= \lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{1}{h} \cdot h \cdot \frac{0^4 + 4 \cdot 0^2 h^2 - h^4}{(0^2 + h^2)^2} \\
&= \lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{-h^4}{(h^2)^2} = -1.
\end{align*}
I'm guessing that $f_{yx}(0, 0) = 1$, but you'll have to check for yourself.

Comment: yes $f_{yx}(0,0)=1$, but Schwarz's theorem is used to check whether $f_{xy}=f_{yx}$ or not without calculating them.[link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetry_of_second_derivatives)

Comment: I know it under the name Clairaut's theorem. The point is, the theorem has assumptions which this function doesn't satisfy. The point of the exercise to see that the assumptions are important, and that applying it to just any function is risky.